# What do Bottle & Cappy do?

Tags: fallout-shelter

After finishing the "A Refreshing Rescue" Quest, Bottle & Cappy started visiting my Vault.
**What are their effects, other than the happiness boost?** *And how does the happiness boost behave?*

Comment: ...in case you haven't read this post: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286059/who-does-bottle-cappy-cheer-up

Comment: No, that question only asks who they cheer up. This one asks about everything they do. The answer reveals that you can get Caps and Nuka-Cola Quantum from them. @tjeloep

Comment: I answered the other question, and you're clearly looking for more information in this one. I considered adding the additional information regarding the caps and the quantum bottles to the other answer, but it doesn't really fit. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Bottle & Cappy temporarily increase the happiness of all the Vault's Dwellers by 20%, for the duration of their visit.** *Also, tapping on them while doing a cheer-up activity will give you Caps. It might also happen to earn Nuka-Cola Quantum from Bottle.*
[image: Earning Caps and Nuka-Cola Quantum from visitors]

Comment: I've gotten caps from bottle also.

Comment: Yes, I need to edit. Bottle might give you Caps *or* Nuka-Cola Quantum. @Nelson

Comment: I just thought they creeped me out and let Deathclaws into the vault, good to know they actually do something.

Comment: From my experience, Bottle & Cappy don't attract Deathclaws when they open the Vault Door. @nailbones

Comment: In my game, they seemed to attract Deathclaws almost every time they visited. I was in the correct level/resource range. I made sure no other characters were coming and going.

Answer (score 0):

I found that yes, they attract incidents but they also boost happiness. Both will drop rewards when you tap on them while they dance. Bottle will give you 1, 3, or 5, nuca-colas depending on when you tap on her/him (it?). Cappy will give you caps, also depending on when you tap him/her (it?). I found that the longer you let them dance the higher your rewards are.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that Bottle only dances once, and Cappy can perform up to like, 4 times before they leave. Also, yes, they do attract deathclaws. Almost makes me wish they would stop visiting, if you can even turn that off.

Comment: These two NPCs do not actually attract deathclaws per se. Opening the vault door does.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, this is what they do:
~Increase Happiness
~Clicking on Cappy as he performs each time gives you caps
~Clicking on Bottle the one time he performs gives you between 1-3 nuka-colas or caps